AHK : How do I determine if the active window does not match any of the titles in a list?
I got this AHK script made by Shenk from here assign different border to different windows?.
It is designed to draws border around active window :
; =================================================================
global EVENT_SYSTEM_SOUND := 0x1 ; 1 - a sound has been generated
global EVENT_SYSTEM_ALERT := 0x2 ; 2 - alert has been generated
global EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND := 0x3 ; 3 - foreground window changed
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUSTART := 0x4 ; 4 - menu-bar menu opened
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND := 0x5 ; 5 - menu-bar menu closed
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPSTART := 0x6 ; 6 - pop-up menu opened
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPEND := 0x7 ; 7 - pop-up menu closed
global EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTURESTART := 0x8 ; 8 - mouse click start
global EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTUREEND := 0x9 ; 9 - mouse click end
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART := 0xA ; 10 - window move/resize start
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND := 0xB ; 11 - window move/resize end
global EVENT_SYSTEM_SCROLLINGSTART := 0x12 ; 18 - scrolling started on a scrol bar
global EVENT_SYSTEM_SCROLLINGEND := 0x13 ; 19 - scrolling ended on a scrol bar
global EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART := 0x14 ; 20 - alt+tab pressed
global EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND := 0x15 ; 21 - alt+tab released
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART := 0x16 ; 22 - window minimized
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZEEND := 0x17 ; 23 - window restored from minimize
global WINDOW_DRAG_STARTED := 0x19 ; 25 - window drag start (documentation not found for this)
global EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH := 0x20 ; 32 - active desktop has switched
global EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE := 0x8000 ; 32768 - an object has been created
global EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY := 0x8001 ; 32769 - an object has been destroyed
global EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW := 0x8002 ; 32770 - a hidden object is shown
global EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE := 0x800B ; 32779 - an object has changed location, shape, or size
global EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE := 0x800C ; 32780 - an object's Name property has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_VALUECHANGE := 0x800E ; 32782 - an object's Value property has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_PARENTCHANGE := 0x800F ; 32783 - an object has a new parent object
global EVENT_OBJECT_CLOAKED := 0x8017 ; 32791 - a window is cloaked. A cloaked window still exists, but is invisible to the user.
global EVENT_OBJECT_UNCLOAKED := 0x8018 ; 32792 - a window is uncloaked. A cloaked window still exists, but is invisible to the user.
; used in SetWinEventHook (for dwFlags)
global WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT := 0x0000 ; Events are ASYNC
global WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD := 0x0001 ; Don't call back for events generated by this thread
global WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS := 0x0002 ; Don't call back for events generated by threads of this process
; used with the callback function of SetWinEventHook (for idObject and idChild)
global OBJID_WINDOW := 0x00000000 ; 0
global OBJID_SYSMENU := 0xFFFFFFFF ; -1
global OBJID_TITLEBAR := 0xFFFFFFFE ; -2
global OBJID_MENU := 0xFFFFFFFD ; -3
global OBJID_CLIENT := 0xFFFFFFFC ; -4
global OBJID_VSCROLL := 0xFFFFFFFB ; -5
global OBJID_HSCROLL := 0xFFFFFFFA ; -6
global OBJID_SIZEGRIP := 0xFFFFFFF9 ; -7
global OBJID_CARET := 0xFFFFFFF8 ; -8
global OBJID_CURSOR := 0xFFFFFFF7 ; -9
global OBJID_ALERT := 0xFFFFFFF6 ; -10
global OBJID_SOUND := 0xFFFFFFF5 ; -11
global OBJID_QUERYCLASSNAMEIDX := 0xFFFFFFF4 ; -12
global OBJID_NATIVEOM := 0xFFFFFFF3 ; -13
global CHILDID_SELF := 0
; saved for releasing resources appropriately
; Window and System Events
; Object Events
global EVENT_OBJECT_HIDE := 0x8003 ; 32771 - an object has been hidden
global EVENT_OBJECT_REORDER := 0x8004 ; 32772 - an object's z-order has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS := 0x8005 ; 32773 - an object has received focus
global EVENT_OBJECT_SELECTION := 0x8006 ; 32774 - an object's selection has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_SELECTIONADD := 0x8007 ; 32775 - an item has been added to the selection
global EVENT_OBJECT_SELECTIONREMOVE := 0x8008 ; 32776 - an item has been removed from the selection
global EVENT_OBJECT_SELECTIONWITHIN := 0x8009 ; 32777 - a container object's selection has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_STATECHANGE := 0x800A ; 32778 - an object's state has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE := 0x800B ; 32779 - an object has changed location, shape, or size
global EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE := 0x800C ; 32780 - an object's Name property has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_DESCRIPTIONCHANGE := 0x800D ; 32781 - an object's Description property has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_HELPCHANGE := 0x8010 ; 32784 - an object's Help property has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_DEFACTIONCHANGE := 0x8011 ; 32785 - an object's DefaultAction property has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_ACCELERATORCHANGE := 0x8012 ; 32786 - an object's keyboard shortcut has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_LIVEREGIONCHANGED := 0x8019 ; 32793 - a live region property has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_HOSTEDOBJECTSINVALIDATED := 0x8020 ; 32796 - hosted objects are invalidated
global EVENT_OBJECT_DRAGCANCEL := 0x8022 ; 32798 - an object drag operation has been canceled
global EVENT_OBJECT_DRAGCOMPLETE := 0x8023 ; 32799 - an object drag operation has completed
global EVENT_OBJECT_DRAGENTER := 0x8024 ; 32800 - an object has been dragged into a drop target
global EVENT_OBJECT_DRAGLEAVE := 0x8025 ; 32801 - an object has been dragged out of a drop target
global EVENT_OBJECT_DRAGDROPPED := 0x8026 ; 32802 - an object has been dropped in a drop target
global hookProcAdr := ""
global hWinEventHooks := []
; list of windows for which to create a border
; Title is what will be matched with WinActive(Title)
; if the final list entry's Title is "A", it will make the current active window be the "fallback" if none of the others match
global rectList := [{
    Title: "ahk_class PotPlayer64", Rect: DrawRect(2, '33cc33', 4) }
, { Title: "ahk_group desktop", Rect: DrawRect(2, '33cc33', 0) }
, { Title: "ahk_exe ImageGlass.exe", Rect: DrawRect(3, 'red', 3) }
, { Title: "A", Rect: DrawRect(1, 'red', 1) }]
; }, {
;     Title: "A",
;     Rect: DrawRect()]
class DrawRect extends Gui {
    __New(border_thickness := "3", border_color := "red", offset := 0) {
        super.__New("+AlwaysOnTop -Caption +ToolWindow", "GUI4Boarder")
        super.BackColor := border_color
        super.Opt("+E0x08080028") ; WS_EX_NOACTIVATE|WS_EX_LAYERED|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT|WS_EX_TOPMOST
        DllCall("SetLayeredWindowAttributes", "Ptr", super.Hwnd, "Ptr", 0, "UChar", 255, "UInt", 2, "Int") ; allows this "Layered Window" to be visible and makes it fully opaque (i.e. 255)
        this.offset := offset
        this.parentHwnd := 0
        this.x := 0
        this.y := 0
        this.w := 0
        this.h := 0
        this.outerX := offset
        this.outerY := offset
        this.innerX := border_thickness + offset
        this.innerY := border_thickness + offset
        this.IsShowing := false
    }
    UpdatePosition(hwnd) {
        this.parentHwnd := hwnd
        super.Opt("+Owner" this.parentHwnd)
        WinGetPos(&x, &y, &w, &h, this.parentHwnd)
        if (x == this.x && y == this.y && w == this.w && h == this.h)
            return false ; position is thle same as the last time this was checked
        this.x := x
        this.y := y
        this.w := w
        this.h := h
        return true
    }
    Show() {
        outerX2 := this.w - this.outerX
        outerY2 := this.h - this.outerY
        innerX2 := this.w - this.innerX
        innerY2 := this.h - this.innerY
        WinSetRegion(this.outerX "-" this.outerY " " outerX2 "-" this.outerY " " outerX2 "-" outerY2 " " this.outerX "-" outerY2 " " this
            .outerX "-" this.outerY " " this.innerX "-" this.innerY " " innerX2 "-" this.innerY " " innerX2 "-" innerY2 " " this
            .innerX "-" innerY2 " " this.innerX "-" this.innerY, super.Hwnd)
        ; super.Show("w" . this.w . " h" . this.h . " x" . this.x . " y" . this.y . " NoActivate")
        ; Similar to super.OptShow("+E0x800A8"whxy) but also places it at the top of the z-order
        DllCall("SetWindowPos", "Ptr", super.Hwnd, "Ptr", 0, "Int", this.x, "Int", this.y, "Int", this.w, "Int", this.h,
            "UInt", 0x4250, "Int") ; SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_SHOWWINDOW|SWP_NOOWNERZORDER|SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS (0x10|0x40|0x200|0x4000)
        this.IsShowing := true
    }
    Hide() {
        super.Hide()
        this.IsShowing := false
    }
}
ShowRect(hWinEventHook, Event, hWnd, idObject := 0, idChild := 0, dwEventThread := 0, dwmsEventTime := 0) {
    ; Critical -1 ; turns on Critical (making the thread uninterruptible) but disables message checks (via -1)
    Critical "Off"
    ; ignore events for objects that are not windows and events for child objects
    if (idObject !== OBJID_WINDOW || idChild !== CHILDID_SELF)
        return
    for _, value in rectList {
        ; the latter two WinActive checks will exclude the Windows Desktop itself from matching but you can remove them if you aren't using a WinActive("A") gui
        ; if ((winHwnd := WinActive(value.Title)) && !WinActive("ahk_class WorkerW ahk_exe explorer.exe") && !WinActive("ahk_class Progman ahk_exe explorer.exe")) {
        if ((winHwnd := WinActive(value.Title))) {
            ; current active window matches one in the list
            try {
                if (WinGetMinMax("ahk_id " winHwnd) == 0) {
                    ; window is not maximized or minimized
                    if (value.Rect.UpdatePosition(winHwnd) || !value.Rect.IsShowing) {
                        ; window is in a new position or the gui was previously hidden
                        value.Rect.Show()
                    }
                    continue
                }
            }
            ; active window has been maximized, minimized, or no longer exists, so hide the rect
            value.Rect.Hide()
            continue
        }
        ; hide any existing rects for non-matching windows
        if (value.Rect.IsShowing) {
            value.Rect.Hide()
            continue
        }
    }
}
SetWinEventHook(eventMin, eventMax, hmodWinEventProc, lpfnWinEventProc, idProcess, idThread, dwFlags) {
    return DllCall("SetWinEventHook"
        , "UInt", eventMin ; start of event range
        , "UInt", eventMax ; end of event range
        , "UInt", hmodWinEventProc ; handle to DLL that contains the hook function or null
        , "UInt", lpfnWinEventProc ; the callback
        , "UInt", idProcess ; process IDs of interest (0 = all)
        , "UInt", idThread ; thread IDs of interest (0 = all)
        , "UInt", dwFlags ; flags
        , "Ptr") ; returns HWINEVENTHOOK
}
ReleaseResources(ExitReason, ExitCode) {
    global hookProcAdr, hWinEventHook
    loop hWinEventHooks.Length {
        DllCall("UnhookWinEvent", "Ptr", hWinEventHooks.Pop()) ; free up memory from SetWinEventHook
    }
    if (hookProcAdr) {
        CallbackFree(hookProcAdr) ; free up allocated memory from CallbackCreate
        hookProcAdr := ""
    }
}
OnExit(ReleaseResources)
hookProcAdr := CallbackCreate(ShowRect, , 7) ; avoiding fast mode because it may be called from a different thread
; hook on active window change
hWinEventHooks.Push(SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, 0, hookProcAdr, 0, 0,
    WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS))
; hook on window move/resize
hWinEventHooks.Push(SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE, EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE, 0, hookProcAdr, 0, 0,
    WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS))
ShowRect(0, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, WinActive("A")) ; Make a pseudo call when the script is called in order to affect the current active window as well
; =================================================================

I want to check if the active window does not match any of the titles in rectList.
If no match is found:
it will default to using the fallback rectangle (Title: "A", Rect: DrawRect(1, 'red', 1)) for any other active window.
So Something Like this :
if any other active window except the rectList (not in the rectList) {
Title: "A", Rect: DrawRect(1, 'red', 1)
}
I hope what I'm looking for is clear. Any help to do so Please!
